# Keydown event not working as intended. Image is staying still?

Tags: javascript

I have an image here, and it is in an canvas, however pressing the designated key causes nothing to happen. Where did my code go wrong?

```
  let img = document.getElementById("ship");
let player = {
  x: 375,
  y: 550,
  w: 50,
  h: 50,
};
requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw() {
  //Logic
  ctx.drawImage(img, player.x, player.y, player.w, player.h);
  //Draw
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}


document.addEventListener("keydown", move);
function move(event) {
    console.log(event.code);
  if (event.code === 39) {
    player.x = player.x + 50;
  } else if (event.code === 37) {
    player.x = player.x - 50;
  } else if (event.code === 40) {
    player.x = player.y - 50;
  } else if (event.code === 38) {
    player.x = player.y + 50;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `event.code` is a DOMString and not a number as `event.keyCode`.

eg: pressing left arrow will verify `event.keyCode === 37` and `event.code === 'ArrowLeft'`.

Change either `code` to `keyCode`, or the values against which you check `event.code` and you should be good to go :)

Cheers!

Comment: By the way, there's an error: player.x = player.y - 50. Check the X and Y ;)